# Переполнение при использовании рекурсивного метода внутри другого метода

Tags: java

При вызове рекурсивного метода (toCharList) в методе main он не выдает ошибки и программа выдает нужный результат. Но когда я вызываю этот метод в другом методе (charStat), то получаю переполнение стека. Почему так?

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL("http://www.nkode.io/assets/programming/countmychars.txt");
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

    String text = readFromURL(url, input).replaceAll("\\s", "");
    text = text.toLowerCase();


    Map<Character, Integer>  countChar = toCharMap(toCharList(text.toCharArray(), 0));


    String s = countChar.entrySet().stream()
            .map(keySet -> "\'" + keySet.getKey() + "\' : " + keySet.getValue() + " %")
            .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));


    System.out.println(s);
    System.out.println(charStat("http://www.nkode.io/assets/programming/countmychars.txt"));
}


public static String charStat(String l) throws IOException {

    URL link = new URL(l);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(link.openStream()));

    String text = readFromURL(link, reader).replaceAll("\\s", "");
    text = text.toLowerCase();

    Map<Character, Integer>  textChar = toCharMap(toCharList(text.toCharArray(), 0));


    String statistik = textChar.entrySet().stream()
            .map(keySet -> "\'" + keySet.getKey() + "\' : " + keySet.getValue() + " %")
            .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));


    return statistik;
}



public static String readFromURL(URL link, BufferedReader in) throws IOException {

    String line = in.readLine();
    if (line == null) return "";

    return line + "\n" + readFromURL(link, in);
}



public static List<Character> toCharList(char[] textChars, int i) {

    if(textChars.length == i) return new ArrayList<>();

    List<Character> ret =  new ArrayList<>();
    ret.add(textChars[i]);
    ret.addAll(toCharList(textChars, i + 1));

    return ret;
}


public static Map<Character, Integer> toCharMap(List<Character> l) {
    return toCharMap(l.iterator());
}


public static Map<Character, Integer> toCharMap(Iterator it) {
    if (!it.hasNext()) return new HashMap<>();

    Map<Character, Integer> ret = new HashMap<>();
    ret.put((Character)it.next(), 0);
    ret.putAll(toCharMap(it));

    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Нашел сам ошибку. Если брать не слишком большой массив, то программа работает. Если же в программе вызвать два раза рекурсивный метод для большого количества элементов, то возникает переполнение в следствии слишком глубокой рекурсии...

Comment: Попробуйте в свойствах VM увеличить размер стека